# Explain regarding averageif function in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have following data and wanted to calculate the average revenue for small customer (means customers less than 200 users). So I have wrote this formula "AVERAGEIF(B1:B150,">200",C1:C150)" but the average is coming out to be "27909.55". However, it should be 5016.

Please help thank you

Data is attached Users Revenue 355 13506.00 172 8528.00 713 33180.00 919 37906.00 732 30390.00 748 35170.00 567 26524.00 49 2832.00 113 5560.00 71 4488.00 100 4940.00 664 30857.00 199 8270.00 772 34257.00 145 7428.00 418 17216.00 632 32353.00 394 19027.00 703 31508.00 812 33096.00 872 35402.00 720 28575.00 21 943.00 179 10359.00 118 6104.00 104 5939.00 262 12328.00 777 30332.00 308 18753.00 721 26973.00 1025 38919.00 467 22195.00 1063 43473.00 720 25786.00 467 22614.00 542 23600.00 591 30926.00 527 32536.00 380 20492.00 779 23813.00 11 826.00 124 5948.00 260 9265.00 616 24292.00 875 46636.00 1006 48452.00 5 223.00 84 5774.00 314 14765.00 237 15002.00 623 31062.00 90 4208.00 29 1312.00 737 31282.00 1107 38143.00 990 31469.00 491 25706.00 839 35574.00 821 30730.00 481 22146.00 228 12432.00 758 30497.00 34 1230.00 572 24116.00 656 30107.00 494 25130.00 434 19311.00 424 21094.00 745 24871.00 718 41305.00 532 21197.00 844 35427.00 765 42468.00 239 11731.00 23 1090.00 188 10622.00 278 12904.00 386 17115.00 598 29499.00 462 25549.00 421 20602.00 386 23515.00 866 32408.00 107 6588.00 192 8217.00 415 19189.00 371 24098.00 984 37480.00 373 22182.00 452 19493.00 410 16916.00 772 26981.00 946 44385.00 868 48203.00 360 17123.00 103 3895.00 828 48535.00 526 19495.00 96 4316.00 1070 35154.00 1031 44481.00 588 25308.00 943 39233.00 787 46131.00 784 30054.00 67 4266.00 841 30428.00 659 36683.00 852 40148.00 983 34345.00 659 26389.00 1068 41492.00 1048 34222.00 835 35075.00 105 4278.00 964 31623.00 216 11328.00 854 37073.00 667 25832.00 786 34682.00 229 11146.00 74 3276.00 1043 44189.00 58 2236.00 986 34023.00 759 32636.00 925 30996.00 215 10778.00 133 6198.00 491 23427.00 832 37771.00 666 21094.00 926 33474.00 324 15523.00 281 14720.00 44 2214.00 559 22385.00 715 27295.00 211 8161.00 177 8179.00 123 5131.00 252 10627.00 912 37538.00 756 31626.00 191 10347.00 589 24460.00 761 24176.00 264 12283.00 125 4777.00

Comment: `">200"` is greater than 200 not less than.  use `"<200"`

Comment: I already tired that but it did not worked

Answer (score 0):

Change your > to < and it's fine...

[image]